# How do I learn German preposition use?

Tags: preposition

For example, how do I know whether it is

> Ich schreibe etwas *auf* Facebook

or

> Ich schreibe etwas *in* Facebook

Comment: Learn all the verbs. Most of the prepositions follow easy patterns, but not all (just like on English). If you miss a preposition, it sounds ugly, but mostly it leaves your sentence comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich schreibe etwas auf Facebook.

Correct.

> Ich schreibe etwas in Facebook.

Correct.

> Kinder sind über die Mitteilung begeistert.

Correct.

> Kinder sind von de**r** Mitteilung begeistert.

Correct.

Confused? Often, there isn't a single preposition that matches but several.

The difference between *auf* and *in* for example is whether you consider the item a surface or a container. For most things it's common sense but for abstract concepts as Facebook — which may be either a *page*, so it's a surface, or a *book*, so it's a container — both prepositions apply.

The difference between *über* and *von* when talking about abstract concepts is all about reception. If you talk *über* something, this literally means you place the item on the ground in the middle of the group so everyone could watch it while you are talking. If you talk *von* in contrary, it means the item is not within reach and people have to use their imagination.

Comment: Here is another illustration of Janka's argument: *Ich schreibe etwas **in der** Zeitung*: I am a journalist and I publish something in my newspaper. - *Ich schreibe etwas **auf die** Zeitung*: I am a subscriber to that newspaper, read it during breakfast, have a nice idea for today and note it down somewhere on an empty spot in my copy of the newspaper. - *Ich schreibe etwas **an die** Zeitung*: I am upset about something the newsaper wrote, and I send the editors a letter to complain.